# Inaccurate translation of phrases in Latin with word "defender"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

I'm trying to translate the following words to Latin (see blockquote). And I've used various translation tools, but I have a strong feeling it's inaccurate.

These ones I would like to have correctly translated.

> Defender of Europe
>
> European defender
>
> Defend Europe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defender of Europe would be *defensor Europae*.

A European defender, that is someone who is [European](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=europae&la=la#lexicon) and a defender, would be *defensor Europaeus*.

And, to defend Europe can be expressed as *Europam defendere*. **Note:** As Joonas pointed out in the comment, *defendere* might indicate the infinitive, the imperative or certain indicative forms. Depending on what you want to say, the verb should be modified according to person, tense, etc.

Comment: +1! The last one might be intended as a command, "defend Europe!". At leas that's how I read it. Maybe you could point out that different forms of the verb are needed for different uses, (mostly) unlike in English.